# React conditional inline style not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Im having issues inputing this style

The original was the following

```
<div style={{display: "grid", gridTemplateColumns: "2fr 1.1fr", textAlign: "center"}}></div>
```

But im trying to do something like:

```
const gridStyle = {display: "grid", gridTemplateColumns: "2fr 1.1fr", textAlign: "center"}
<div style={noGrid ? {""} : gridStyle}></div>
```

Im basically trying to use an empty style if noGrid is true But apparently i cant assign it like that

> Type 'string | { display: string; gridTemplateColumns: string;
> textAlign: string; }' is not assignable to type 'CSSProperties'.
> Type 'string' has no properties in common with type 'Properties<string
> | number>'.ts(2322)

Comment: `{""}` is not a valid CSSProperties, change it to `style={!noGrid && gridStyle}`

Comment: You need to first: `const gridStyle = {display: "grid", gridTemplateColumns: "2fr 1.1fr", textAlign: "center"} as const` And then change your second line to`<div style={noGrid ? undefined : gridStyle}></div>`

Answer (score -1):

I think your first case render is not in the correct format for css. Maybe something like

`<div style={noGrid ? {} : gridStyle }></div>`

Would work?

Comment: None is not a thing in JS nor TS